# Installing Microsoft's ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to use pyodbc python package on raspberry pi 4. I install pyodbc and then I followed this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 to download the ODBC driver but I get this error when I run my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/water.py", line 22, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I believe my machine doesn't find the ODBC driver 17 that I just downloaded. Although, I can see all the odbc file downloaded under usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc.

Could someone help me to use import pyodbc on a rpi4?
Here is the line where the error is found in my script:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER = {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER = projectdb.database.windows.net; DATABASE = projectdb; UID= AppLogin; PWD= 87dwwg4ed')
```

Comment: Start by removing the spaces immediately before and after each equals sign, e.g., `DRIVER={ODBC Driver …};SERVER=projectdb…`. Those extra spaces can cause problems in some environments.

Comment: Yeah that's not the problem, I removed the spaces in my code already

Comment: Run `odbcinst -j` at a command prompt to verify the location of the "odbcinst.ini" file, then look at the contents of that file to see if it contains a valid `[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]` section.

Comment: There's nothing in the file

Comment: Okay, so that explains the error. What does `odbcinst -j` report as the path to the "odbcinst.ini" file?

Comment: it says /etc/odbcinst.ini

Comment: … and did you actually find "libmsodbcsql-17.6.so.1.1" somewhere under "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc"? (The msodbcsql installer normally installs the file to "/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.6.so.1.1".)

Answer (score 0):

> I can see all the odbc file downloaded under usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc.

The path suggests that your Pi is using the Arm architecture. It is very possible that Microsoft does not offer a package for Arm. The product list for Buster …

https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list

… only lists the `amd64` architecture:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster main
```

So, you may need to use FreeTDS ODBC instead:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt install tdsodbc
```

(That seems to be what most Raspberry Pi users are doing based on other questions I've seen.)